# Unable to get urls indexed by google console

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-search-console

I have 2 URLs that have been in Discovered - currently not indexed state for more then 3 months. Upon doing a URL inspection I have gotten the following error "URL is not on Google". Attaching a screenshot of what is on URL inspection

[image]

Upon doing a live test of URL i have gotten the following result

[image]

from what I understand there shouldn't be a reason for them to not be indexed. I have checked Robots.txt file for any blockers as well.
since this is a wordpress site I made sure to check if any pluging (yoast SEO) is causing a blocker, but that also isn't the case

I am facing issue mainly with "https://www.yapsody.com/ticketing/features/online-payment-gateways/"

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IndexGuru or similar tools like that can likely fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I now view it indexed, check on Google like this site:https://www.yapsody.com/ticketing/features/online-payment-gateways/

From Search Console you can always suggest indexing the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking. It's a Google system error for my experience. High possibility to fix it automatically. You should wait a few days.